# Нужна ли запятая после "Вот"?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая: "Вот(,) что я люблю!"?

Answer (score 7):

**ВОТ** - частица, которая в данном предложении употреблена для уточнения и усиления значения последующего слова или высказывания в целом. Никакой запятой не нужно. Н-р: *Вот на кого надежда. Вот в чём вопрос.*

Answer (score 6):

Согласна  с автором вопроса, что это сложноподчиненное предложение с неполной главной частью. Ведь если предложение простое, то какой разряд у местоимения "что"? Относительное местоимение употребляется в сложном. И само по себе наличие относительного местоимения - аргумент в пользу сложноподчиненного. Но вот запятую мне ставить не хочется. Даже если это не в рекламном слогане (в рекламе какое-то свое, вольное обращение с нормами). Это, конечно, не аргумент. 
Вот еще о чем подумалось. Хотя этого и нет в правилах (но и подобного предложения я не нашла ни у Розенталя, ни у Лопатина - ни среди простых предложений, ни среди сложных), может, дело в том, что главная часть сильно усечена. Нет слова, от которого задаем вопрос к придаточному. Частицы не связаны с другими словами в предложении.

Comment: Я согласен с тем, что нет слова, от которого задаем вопрос к придаточному. Но оно же подразумевается наличием этого самого указательного местоимения ВОТ.

Другое дело, что многие считают, что ВОТ - это частица, а не местоимение. Конечно, обе эти версии имеют право на жизнь. Но так как в той же Википедии есть версия, по которой ВОТ - это идентификационное указательное местоимение, и, значит, оно может быть подлежащим, что делает этот слоган сложноподчинённым предложением, а запятая перед ЧТО ставится в таких предложения, как в нашем случае и есть, я всё же уверен в том, что запятая должна быть

Comment: Вот- указательная частица

Comment: Ларf,а если Вы будете разбирать в классе, разве не так разберёте:Вот что я люблю. Я-подлежащее, люблю-сказуемое, люблю что?- "вот что"-дополнение.Вот что= вот это, отсылает нас к предыдущему контексту(продукции Макдональдса).Вот пример на правило "Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым в простом предложении":Разум да сердце – вот что в человеке дорого. (сказ."вот что дорого")Прямое указание на простое предложение. "А еще вот что, Лойко"-это тоже сложное предложение?Иногда придаточное предложение, состоящее из одного союзного слова превращается в член предложения и не отделяется запятой.

Comment: А "Вот в чём вопрос"-тоже сложноподчинённое? Вопрос-подлежащее, вот в чём-дополнение со знач. обстоятельства, сказуемое пропущено - эллипсис.

Comment: Ларf, Вы правы: изначально это сложноподчинённое предложение с  усечённым главным предложением, в котором осталась только частица. Ср.: Вот [то], что я люблю!  Запятая перед ЧТО в предложении ВОТ ЧТО Я ЛЮБЛЮ не ставится, так как от частицы вопрос к придаточной части задать невозможно. Потеряв слово ТО, к которому частица относилась,  она просто примыкает к придаточному, и предложение превращается в простое.

Comment: Катя, я согласна с Вами. Но тогда и относительным местоимение что назвать уже нельзя. Оно приобретает какое-то указательное значение.

Comment: Очень интересно. Пожалуй, Вы правы.

Answer (score 5):

В слогане Макдональдса: "Вот что я люблю!" – нет запятой. Вот –  частица, которая употребляется с указательными и относительными местоимениями, а также с наречиями места, времени, причины и т. п. для уточнения и усиления их значения ◆  — А что? Вот я какой — в шляпе, при галстуке… ◆ Вот в чём вопрос. Предложение простое.

Вариант с запятой возможен в диалоге в неполных предложениях. Тогда ВОТ будет словом-предложением со смыслом "Да, точно так", а дальше уточняется, что именно "так": "Вот, (это то,) что я люблю". Но это не диалог – слоган, то есть независимое утверждение.

В приведённой конструкции предложение простое с усилительной частицей  – запятой нет.
Я – подлежащее, люблю – сказуемое. Люблю что? – "вот что" – дополнение. Предложение простое.

Comment: Да Вы сами себе противоречите!
Вы пишите:
"Вариант с запятой возможен ... в неполных предложениях."
И приводите пример:
"Вот,( это то,) что я люблю."
А потом утверждаете, что это предложение простое с усилительной частицей.

Comment: Возможен в ДИАЛОГЕ, в неполных предложениях, а у Вас не диалог, а слоган.В примере я в скобках указала смысл, пропущенные, но подразумевающиеся слова, в слогане этого смысла нет - там утверждение, усиливающееся частицей ВОТ. ВОТ ЧТО=ВОТ ЭТО

Comment: Да как же в слогане этого смысла нет, когда "Вот,(ОНО,) что я люблю!".
И это ОНО в данном случае и есть это пропущенное, но подразумевающееся слово. А значит, "Вот, (ОНО,)" - простое неполное предложение в составе сложного.

Answer (score 4):

*Вот что* - это специальная "вопросо-ответная" конструкция.

> Существенную роль в образовании с
> указательным смыслом играет частица вот.
> Прежде всего это *зависимость от предыдущего
> контекста*, идущая от местоименно-указательного «происхождения» частицы. 
> Таким образом, анафорическое значение
> частицы вот (восходящее к частице тъ) и
> постоянное ударение на ней при сочетании с
> вопросительными местоимениями (а во всяком
> вопросе есть и обобщенное указание)
> позволяет считать **сращение типа вот что**
> *грамматико-смысловым объединением на
> основе указательности.* Вопросительность
> нейтрализуется частицей вот. С частицей **вот**
> связана и *повышенная экспрессивная
> окрашенность.*

[Ссылка](http://центры-тестирования.рф/tema4/mestoimenie-v-sochetanii-s-chasticei.html)

Вот вам и ответ на вопрос! Предложение простое. В рекламном слогане - "повышенная экспрессивная окрашенность" и подчеркнутая указательность на подразумеваемый вопрос :

-- Ты **что** любишь?

-- **Вот что** я люблю!

Comment: Ну что же, только пройдя по Вашей ссылке, я вынужден с согласиться с тем, что ВОТ ЧТО - это специальная "вопросо-ответная" конструкция.
Спасибо Вам за ответ!

Comment: grumant! Спасибо, что нашли хоть это. Ведь в пользу сложного для меня был главный аргумент - наличие явно не вопросительного (а значит, относительного) местоимения что. Я чувствую, что оно становится указательным. Но никогда не встречала такого в теории. Хорошо бы еще где-нибудь (а не только в источнике от Исмаиловой Наили Шавкатовны из Узбекистана) это почитать.

Comment: deryabo! Вместе со спасибо хорошо бы поставить плюс - нажать на палец, поднятый вверх.

Answer (score 0):

---

- Если это прямая речь то ДА! Если
     простое предложение то НЕТ

---

> yupaz специально для тебя!)
> ***Простое предложение** – это такое предложение, в котором имеется одна грамматическая основа. Она может состоять из двух главных членов – **подлежащего** и **сказуемого**,

- **Например**: С чего начинается Родина? -

или из одного – **подлежащего**,

- Например: Зима. Кругом лежит снег -

**сказуемого**,

- Например: Вечереет. Небо на западе
     порозовело.*

Comment: как это - простое предложение?

Comment: Вообще-то, это рекламный слоган Макдональдса. "Вот(,) что я люблю!"
И хотя я не в курсе, слоган - это прямая речь или нет, да и при чём здесь это правило (?), но я, уж извините, не склонен особо доверять человеку, допускающему две пунктуационные ошибки в двух коротких предложениях.

Comment: Если я не поставил тире(-) или запятую(,) , то это в социальном мире не важно) Да согласен в русском языке на диктанте это бы засчитали как ошибку) Я сам за правильное написание слов) Но из-за этого делать такую трагедию не надо) Я много тут видел ошибок) Но конфликт я из этого не делал)

Comment: А никто из этого трагедию и не делает.

Я лишь хотел напомнить Вам, где мы с Вами находимся. А находимся мы на сайте "Русский язык" в разделе "Пунктуация".

И это всё! :-)

Comment: И еще, мне кажется, что yupaz имел ввиду, как это - если простое предложение, то НЕТ?

Ведь это же простое неполное предложение в составе сложного, а значит - именно, ДА.

Comment: @Sm0ke, спасибо за разъяснение! Сразу стало всё понятно, особенно ваше противопоставление "прямая речь" - "простое предложение".
@deryabo, я как раз считаю наоборот: это предложение сложное, где "вот что" - указательное местоимение с указательной частицей, относящееся к сказуемому. Люблю что? - вот что.

Comment: Да, но ЧТО - это, вообще-то, относительное местоимение.

Answer (score 0):

Вот (то), что я люблю. Как носители языка мы понимаем интуитивно, что здесь опущено (то), которое и определяется второй частью предложения. Запятая, конечно, нужна.

Answer (score -1):

А мне кажется, что ВОТ - в данном случае это указательное местоимение, которое подразумевает наличие подлежащего (ОНО), и данное предложение является сложноподчинённым, а поэтому запятая должна быть.

Comment: и как быть с правилом постановки запятой перед ЧТО?

Comment: Запятая перед "что"ставится в сложноподчинённых предложениях, а не в простых, здесь простое.

Comment: Я уже писал, что ВОТ - в данном случае это указательное местоимение, которое подразумевает наличие подлежащего (ОНО), и данное предложение является сложноподчинённым, а поэтому запятая должна быть. А тем более Вы сами подтвердили, что запятая перед "что" ставится в сложноподчинённых предложениях.

Comment: deryabo: и как быть с правилом постановки запятой перед ЧТО?

Я даже не сразу поняла, о каком правиле идет речь. Вероятно, из учебника начальной школы: перед словами а, что,если,  но ставится запятая. Но это не так! В это утверждение хорошо бы добавить "чаще всего", ведь предложения бывают гораздо более сложными, чем в учебнике первого-второго класса. Не будет запятой, например, перед что в предложении с однородными придаточными.