# "Вот(,) в чем вопрос"

Tags: пунктуация

Знаменитое: "Быть или не быть — вот(,) в чем вопрос". Что-то меня заклинило: нужна запятая после "вот" или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не так давно обсуждали. Смотрите [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/20207/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82)