# Нужна ли запятая? ***

Tags: пунктуация

"Все что мне сейчас нужно" нужна ли запятая перед что?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Нужна ли запятая после "Вот"?](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/20207/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%92%d0%be%d1%82)

Comment: Ой, простите, мне показалось, что у Вас "**вот** что", а не "всё, что", и я проголосовал за закрытие, п. ч. якобы дубликат. :(

Answer (score 1):

Запятая нужна.

> Запятая не ставится перед подчинительным союзом или союзным словом в составе неразложимых сочетаний: достать что нужно (но: достать всё, что нужно).

Источник: [тык сюда](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827524.html)